# Почему этот фрагмент программы не является решением?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Уровень C. Напишите программу, которая заменяет во всей строке одну последовательность символов на другую.
Пример:
Введите строку:
**(X > 0) and (Y < X) and (Z > Y) and (Z <> 5)**
Что меняем: **and**
Чем заменить: **&**
Результат
**(X > 0) & (Y < X) & (Z > Y) & (Z <> 5)**

```
s = "(X > 0) and (Y < X) and (Z > Y) and (Z <> 5)"
s_need = str(input('Что ищем?'))
s_change = str(input('Чем заменяем'))
while s_need in s:
    del s[s.index(s_need)]
```

Почему del не работает

Comment: Наверное потому, что строки в python неизменяемы. Вы же понимаете, что пытаетесь удалить элемент списка(массива), а даете в качестве аргумента строку? И самое главное - зачем вам вообще `del`?

Comment: del s[Тут индекс удаляемого элемента],  я подумал, что можно сделать так. Но я уже понял ошибку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте лучше так:

```
s = "(X > 0) and (Y < X) and (Z > Y) and (Z <> 5)"
s_need = input('Что ищем? ')
s_change = input('Чем заменяем: ')
s = s.replace(s_need, s_change)
```